# Name attribute is missing in html email

Tags: html, email

I would like to ask if any of you have an idea why the name attribute is missing when html is sent as an email?

```
<img src="http://somepic.jpg" alt="some_alt_message" name="some_name" />
```

becomes

```
<img src="http://somepic.jpg" alt="some_alt_message"  />
```

Comment: It probably is the email client, but why do you need the `name` attribute to be present in an email and on an image of all things anyway?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the image tag doesn't support the name attribute. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html

And/or the email parsing is stripping it because it's not a valid attribute.

http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/img.html#name

"In XHTML 1.0 the "name" attribute for this element has been deprecated in favor of the "id" attribute and in XHTML 1.1 it's simply invalid. Therefore, its use is no longer recommended."

Comment: HTML 3 is an odd choice of reference; it never made it past *draft* status.

Comment: I didn't know that!, pretty neat. The article didn't show the HTML 'version', but I notice the URL now.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the software used to compose, send, transmit, or read the email message. Without further information, it is hardly possible to identify the guilty.

The `name` attribute is, practically speaking, used only in client-side scripting, in order to select a particular element in JavaScript. If it causes real problems that some software removes the attribute, consider using the more standard (these days) `id` attribute instead.